# Assigning cards in Trello with different permissions

Tags: trello, permissions

Is there away to assign individuals to the card in Trello, so only they can move the card through the workflow and not be able to edit/move lists?

I run a charitable organisation and need a way to run sessions through a regular six step process currently set up as lists. For each job I would like to assign three members to the card and allow only them to move through the card through the workflow (lists).

Currently I can only see how all members can move/edit and delete cards/lists.

Comment: Although the question is a logical one and I understand that you would like to use it: Don't you trust your board members?

Answer (score 3):

No, Trello does not offer fine-grained permissions of this type. Sorry. In the future, it might be possible to write a plugin or an API monitoring script. This could be made to alert you if a card was moved by someone not assigned to it.

But, as of now and for the near future, this does not exist.